ValueError with win_type 'bohman' in pandas rolling function after upgrading to Python 3.11
I am encountering an issue with the pandas library in Python after upgrading from Python 3.8 to Python 3.11, while using the same pandas version (1.5.3). When I attempt to use the 'rolling' method with 'bohman' as the window type, it results in a ValueError. The problematic code is as follows:
p_spp_mean = p_spp_in.rolling(
    window, closed='left', center=True, win_type=self._smoothing_method
).mean()

self._smoothing_method = par.get('smoothing_method', 'bohman')


The error message I receive is:
raise ValueError(f"Invalid win_type {self.win_type}")
ValueError: Invalid win_type bohman

I tested the rolling function with another window type 'gaussian' on a simple DataFrame in a Jupyter notebook and it worked as expected:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create a simple DataFrame
data = {
    'date': pd.date_range(start='2023-01-01', periods=10, freq='D'),
    'values': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Apply a Gaussian rolling window to the 'values' column
df['gaussian_rolling_sum'] = df['values'].rolling(window=2, win_type='gaussian').sum(std=3)

print(df)

However, using 'bohman' as the window type now requires a workaround involving manually applying the window using scipy.signal:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal

# Create a simple DataFrame
data = {
    'date': pd.date_range(start='2023-01-01', periods=10, freq='D'),
    'values': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Function to apply the Bohman window
def bohman_window(x):
    window = signal.get_window('bohman', len(x))
    return np.sum(window * x) / np.sum(window)

# Apply a Bohman rolling window to the 'values' column
df['bohman_rolling_sum'] = df['values'].rolling(window=3).apply(bohman_window)

I was expecting the 'bohman' win_type to work as it did in Python 3.8 without requiring additional libraries or manual implementations. I am unsure why this error occurs and how to adapt my code appropriately.
Has anyone experienced similar issues with window types in pandas when upgrading Python versions? How can I resolve the 'Invalid win_type' error without resorting to manual implementations for standard window types like 'bohman'? Is there a better approach to handling this incompatibility between Python and pandas versions?

Here is the origin of the error. It seems that there are only two possibilities. One, is that self._smoothing_method is not a str. The other, is that you do not have scipy installed on your python v3.11.

Actually, scipy is installed correctly, and the problem arises when I migrate the version of scipy from 1.11.0 to 1.13.0.
self._smoothing_method is a str ( = 'bohman')

For information: by going back to scipy 1.12 I got this DeprecationWarning: Importing bohman from 'scipy.signal' is deprecated since SciPy 1.1.0 and will raise an error in SciPy 1.13.0. Please use 'scipy.signal.windows.bohman' or the convenience function 'scipy.signal.get_window' instead.

But it doesn't work event i f I follow the deprecation warning
